# Is it recommended to back up my files before dual boot with ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, backup

I only want to know if it´s recommended to backup pc files before performing the installation of ubuntu for dual boot.

Comment: You should always backup no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You should always back up any personal files from your operating system to an external hard drive or USB. This is a really good habit to have because it can save you from otherwise devastating issues while installing another operating system. It's extremely risky to leave personal files *only* on the computer that you're modifying. This goes for any time you modify a computer on a level of partitioning and operating systems. Hope this helps to guide you to perform a successful dual-boot.

Answer (score 1):

Having a current backup is always a safe consideration when using the computer.  The hard drive can always fail.

As far as the installing of Ubuntu, it's very safe and robust.  In my experience the only time I've see a person have a problems is when they specified something different from their intention, such as specifically deleting a partition with data they wanted to keep.

In over 20 years of editing partitions (creating, resizing, moving, deleting, etc), I've never experienced any difference with using the partition editor than I've experience with using a word processor editor.

It's up to the user to be careful when making changes to the content of his hard drive.

Gparted and Ubuntu (as well as the Windows Partition manager is very robust.

Comment: Hmm thanks! How many size of partition should I put for my ubuntu?

Comment: I would recommend at least 50 Gigs.  If using the alongside Windows option, the installer will allocate some of the space for swap.  You should try to have enough space for 1 1/2 the size of the amount of RAM you have and have at least 50 gigs left.  If you have 8 gigs of ram, you'd best allocate (if you have it available) at least 65 gigs for Ubuntu.

Comment: I have 6 gb of ram

Comment: With such amount of RAM you'll rarely if ever need swap but if you want some then ~2GB should be enough (unless you intend to hibernate in which case make the same as RAM). The 2x (or 1 1/2) the RAM is outdated information.

Comment: @CarlosYanes In that case, the specifying at least 65 would suffice.  The installer will take care of the swap partition.  It'll create an extended partition then make two partitions in that space.  One for the actual Ubuntu install and one for swap.  I'll have enough space to provide a recommended swap space for you.   So you won't need to worry about the swap space unless you are going to create the partitions yourself.  That's when you should ensure you have the recommended amount of swap space.

Comment: I don´t follow you. When partitioning i should create a partition with space on the HD but also with the ram?}

Comment: @CarlosYanes If you use the alongside Windows option, you won't have to create a partition.  The Ubuntu installer will give you a slider.  Use that slider to specify how much space you want to allow Ubuntu to use.  The installer will handle it from there.  By the way, if the developers thought you didn't need any swap space, they would never include it in the process.  I gave the details FYI so that you would know what's happening.